# Text classification with imbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, text-classification, imbalanced-data

Am trying to classify 10000 samples of text into 20 classes. 4 of the classes have just 1 sample each, I tried SMOTE to address this imbalance, but I am unable to generate new samples for classes that have only one record, though I could generate samples for classes with more than 1 sample. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A good explainer (and a potential answer to your question on why it might not have worked on the undersampled classes) on SMOTE can be found in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27671/how-do-you-apply-smote-on-text-classification).

I think this issue can't be solved easily through off-the-shelf data augmentation strategies. One possibility might be to simply duplicate the example, but this would add no new information to your model.

Here are a couple other strategies you could try as well:

1. An embedding-based augmentation technique (similar theory to SMOTE but works better on text data) that's described in this [2015 paper by William Wang and Diyi Yang](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1306.pdf).
2. A step further on #1 using contextualized word embeddings described here in this [2017 paper by Marzieh Fadaee, Arianna Bisazza, and Christof Monz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00440.pdf).
3. Use a synonym replacement library like WordNetAug.

Comment: Thank you @nlpnoah, i tried bert synonyms, and got some positive results.